# Why doesn't Imagemagick's import utility work when called from async-shell-command, but works as expected when called from vterm?

Tags: shell-command, exwm

I'm trying to get screenshots working in EXWM. From vterm if I issue the command `import png:- | xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png` this turns my mouse cursor into a crosshair, prompting me for a rectangular selection to screenshot. Once the screenshot is complete I can use C-v to paste it as I would regularly.

However, if I try to do any of the following (where the second snippet uses general.el):

```lisp
(setq desktop-environment-screenshot-command "import png:- | xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png")
```

```lisp
(nvmap :keymaps 'override
  "c-<print>" '(lambda () (interactive)
         (async-shell-command "import png:- | xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png")))
```

Or running the initial command through `async-shell-command` invoked through `M-&`, I get the crosshair prompt, but cannot paste the results anywhere. Why does this happen, and how can I get imagemagick's import utility to take screenshots from selections in EXWM?

Thank you.